# Special character from an arXiv paper title displayed incorrectly in Google Scholar

Tags: arxiv, latex, google-scholar

Recently I uploaded a paper to arxiv.org, the title contains the letter (α), I wrote it in latex form $\alpha$ in the website, it recognize it and it is displayed correctly, but when the paper is indexed in Google scholar, it appears as $\alpha$ in the title, any idea how can I fix this?

[arxiv Link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.00976)

[Google Scholar Link](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=fLUdXLgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=fLUdXLgAAAAJ:d1gkVwhDpl0C)

Comment: I doubt that you can fix it.  But I wouldn't worry too much; I think readers in technical fields are used to issues like this, and will not have any trouble parsing your title.

Comment: This should be posted at [Tex.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @fileunderwater: I don't think so: it's basically a question about Google Scholar, not about TeX.

Comment: @fileunderwater - First question to ask before migrating: "Is this on-topic here?" If "yes", then no migration necessary, even if it's *more* on-topic elsewhere.

Comment: Do you mind linking to the paper in question? It might be difficult to know how to fix it otherwise..

Comment: Your target audience won't even notice - they compile it when they look it. It's like the the old joke that no one notices if you put two "the"s next to each other in a sentence, like I just did.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect that Google Scholar is getting the page title from the metadata of the arXiv page, which has the following title metadata (look at the HTML page source in your browser to see it):

> [1509.00976] In-Band $\alpha$-Duplex Scheme for Cellular Networks: A Stochastic Geometry Approach

The good news is, you can edit how your own papers appear in Google Scholar.

- Create a Google Scholar account if you don't already have one. Then sign in to your account.
- Click on "My Library."
- Then click on the paper in question, click on "Edit," make your changes, and hit "Save."

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that I can edit the title.